# Change the favicon in an image url

Tags: php, html, favicon, titlebar

I want to change the *favicon of resources* html display pages. I mean when i go to the image url i want to see my icon in the title bar not the icon of the server (in my case XAMPP).

Comment: post some code and explain more about your question

Comment: When we type in the url the path of the images that we use in our website for example : https://localhost/example/img/image1.png . The favicon that appears is the logo of xampp. How can i change it ?

Comment: I had already answered this question. Check out this link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42017692/how-to-replace-the-xampp-favicon-with-my-own-one

Comment: I had already answered this question. Check out this link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42017692/how-to-replace-the-xampp-favicon-with-my-own-one

Answer (score 3):

Add this to the `<head>` of your file:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
```

make sure that the href link is correct.

Comment: Where I put this code ? I use a MVC project. So the views aren't in the same directory with the ressources

Comment: Just place it in the same place you link up the css files its the same concept

Answer (score 2):

Just put an ICO file named `favicon.ico` in document root.

A quick test is to open the URL `http://my.domain/favicon.ico` in a browser; it should display the icon.

Note that the icon file MUST be in document root. 
If you can't put the file there physically, you could use Apache's `mod_alias` to map the file to this URL. 
This is done by placing the following line in your server's configuration (`httpd.conf` file):

```
alias /favicon.ico /path/to/your/images/directory/favicon.ico
```

Comment: Is it a valid ICO file? 
And is it displayed if you open the URL `http://localhost/favicon.ico` in your browser?

Comment: Yes, it is a valid ico file. Well my website is build as MVC php project so my images aren't in the same directory with the views.

Comment: `favicon.ico` must be in document root for this to work. You could use Apache's `mod_alias` or `mod_rewrite` if you can't physically put the icon file in document root.

Comment: Should I declare <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico"/> somewhere?

Comment: `<link rel="icon" ...>` should be placed in your HTML pages, but it won't help with static resources like images.

Comment: Sorry, there aren't many alternatives in case of image resources rather than placing `favicon.ico` in root. 
Why do you actually care about the favicon on image URLs? 
If you present direct links to images in your website, you could wrap the images in a minimal HTML, which would give you much more control on Favicon and other stuff...

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I will try to make a html page to control the favicon.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="images/favicon.ico"/>
```

[Read this Blog Article as well](http://blogs.adobe.com/contribute/2011/06/how-to-add-favicon-to-your-website.html)

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me finally

Answer (score 0):

As the other posters have stated, you need to edit your HTML and in the  section, add the line to show the favicon you have uploaded.

If you look at the source for this page, the line defining the favicon is this:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=6cd6089ee7f6">
```

but the code stated elsewhere here will also work (`<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico"/>`)

Many browsers will automatically look for the favicon.ico in the root of the webserver (as Alex Shesterov wrote in a comment)