# how to replace the xampp favicon with my own one?

Tags: xampp

trying to edit the xampp favicon but coudn't do that so revomed them. now my webpages don't even have xampp favicon and i'm unable to add my own icon.can someone walk me through the whole process that really works. if can't then just teach me how to add an icon on a real server where my site soon going to b hosted? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

just add the code bellow to your file.

```html
<head>
<link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/ico">
</head>
```

Comment: which file should be updated?

Answer (score 6):

I think that this will work for you.

Just go to C:\xampp\htdocs and delete the favicon.ico file (if it is there).
Insert the image file in that folder. (Remember that it should be an ico type file)
Now rename that image as 'favicon' and it will be done.

Answer (score 2):

Adding an icon named `favicon.ico` **in your document root** should solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, even after you changed the favicon.ico file, the browser still cached the old favicon.

You need to do CTRL+F5 on the browser to reload the page.